# Is there any way to enforce a minimum browser window size in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, responsive

I'm trying to make a web app with some degree of responsiveness, and I noted that some applications limit the minimum size the browser window can have. Is there any way to do this in Flutter?

I found `ResizeObserver` in dart:html, but I can't observe the window.